# (Fragment) How to switch Tab and refresh its page using TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have 2 `tabs` ( **INFO** and **EDIT** ) inside a `Fragment`.

I am successfully able to switch tab from **EDIT** to **INFO** when the user clicked "**UPDATE**" from the **EDIT** tab.

I am using this to switch tab:

```
 TabLayout tabs = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.leads_info_tablayout);
                    tabs.getTabAt(0).select();
```

But then the information isn't updated. I want to refresh the page of the tab so that it can collect the updated info.

Comment: Can you post your fragments too and the fragment creation logic? The behaviour you are trying to achieve i.e. refresh is more like a web thing, in Android we can modify something called as a lifecycle which in this case will be handled by the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Comment: I'm using an Adapter that extends FragmentStateAdapter

Comment: You can try overriding `onResume` of your `Fragment` class and do your refresh logic there

Comment: Read up about Fragment Lifecycle to know more

Comment: Thank you for this. I have read the docs but I'm quite new to this. I could simply call new Fragment transaction but I think this would be a much nicer approach. If you could provide a sample on how to override onResume of INFO Fragment from Edit Fragment I would mark it as an answer.

Comment: You should add both the fragments code, only then I'll be able to suggest something